# Associated Extension with batch file, get filename to batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a files

`1.pt1, 2.pt1, 3.pt1 ....`

```
(the *.pt1 is associated with with test.bat in windows)
```

in bat file is this commnad:

```
 ..\IMPORT.EXE "FILENAME" /format:6
```

And i need put there the real file name 1.ptj1, 2.ptj1 ...

Thank you Rasto

I try to use %~nx0 but instead pt1 file i gete there the test.bat filename....

Comment: Try %~nx1 which will be the first argument passed to the batch file

Comment: thank you, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
echo "%~nx1"
..\IMPORT.EXE "%~nx1" /format:6
```